# Mismatch Error when using CInt(Right())

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I'm using the following code to identify the last populated row in a spreadsheet and the first empty row following, and using this information I figure out what to populate the first cell of the empty row with (PC 1, PC 2, PC 3, etc.). I keep getting a "type-mismatch" error when I try to run it however, and I'm not sure what I need to change to fix it. Below is the code in question, I've added a comment *just above* the line where the debugger stops.

```
    'Creates variable for the next empty row and for PC #.
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim NewPC As Long

    'Determines last row.
    lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'Determines empty row.
    emptyRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Determines PC entry value  <--- DEBUGGER STOPS ON FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE.
    NewPC = CInt(Right(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, Len(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value) - InStrRev(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, " "))) + 1

    'Makes PC Data Sheet active.
    Sheet1.Activate

    'Enters PC # data into first column.
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "PC" & " " & NewPC
```

Got it! Here's the changed line:

```
    'Determines PC entry value
    If lastRow = 1 Then
        NewPC = 1
    Else
        NewPC = Right(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, Len(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value) - InStrRev(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, " ")) + 1
    End If
```

Comment: You're likely getting a string that isn't numeric after chopping off at the last space.  Put `Debug.Print Cells(lastRow, 1).Value` above your `NewPC` assignment and see what's in the cell it returns. BTW, you should probably use `CLng` - there's also the possibility of getting an overflow error on `CInt`  (granted it will be a *lot* of PCs before that happens).

Comment: @Comintern - see my comment to the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that what is actually in `Cells(lastRow, 1).Value` is interpretable as a `String`? If it is an error, it won't be valid to do string operations on it.

Comment: @Comintern & AnotherParker - You're right, I checked and noticed that lastRow is populated by "PC #", hence the type-mismatch. My top row is frozen because it holds column headers and buttons to access userforms, but is included in `lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`. Any good suggestions on how to change it so it doesn't call that first row? Dirty fix is to use "PC 0", but that becomes something that can be deleted by another userform I have...

Comment: @Comintern - Thanks!! That did it! I edited my question above to include the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting the space too. How about:

```
NewPC = CInt(Mid(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, InStrRev(Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, " ")))
```

Comment: CInt doesn't care about spaces: `Debug.Print CInt(" 42")`